# android lintoptions with baseline file is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lint

I have a project which has few lint warnings. For newly created changes if there are any lint warnings I want the build to fail. 
To do that I have added following options in gradle file.

```
lintOptions {
  baseline file("lint-baseline.xml")
  lintConfig file("lint.xml")
  warningsAsErrors true
  abortOnError true
}
```

Build fails for the newly created lint warnings. If resolved, it still fails pointing to old issues recorded in lint-baseline.xml

Error :

Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
...

Errors found:

/.../app/lint-baseline.xml: Error: 3 errors were filtered out because they are listed in the baseline file, lint-baseline.xml
 [LintBaseline]

Answer (score 0):

could you try regenerating the baseline file?
Often the hardcoded LOC in baseline files gets out of date due to other changes in the code.